# Find the Most Recent Matching in an Array [R]

Tags: r, vectorization

Imagine an array of numbers called A.  At each level of A, you want to find the most recent item with a matching value.  You could easily do this with a for loop as follows:

```
A = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2)

for(i in 1:length(A)){   
  if(i > 1 & sum(A[1:i-1] == A[i]) > 0){ 
    answer[i] = max(which(A[1:i-1] == A[i]))
  }else{
    answer[i] = NA
  }
}
```

But I want vectorize this for loop (because I'll be applying this principle on a very large data set).  I tried using sapply:

```
answer = sapply(A, FUN = function(x){max(which(A == x))})
```

As you can see, I need some way of reducing the array to only values that come before x.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq_along` to loop over the index of each element and then subset it and get the `max` index where the value last occured.

```
c(NA, sapply(seq_along(A)[-1], function(x) max(which(A[1:(x-1)] == A[x]))))
#[1]   NA    1 -Inf    3    2    4    6
```

We can change the `-Inf` to `NA` if needed in that format

```
inds <- c(NA, sapply(seq_along(A)[-1], function(x) max(which(A[1:(x-1)] == A[x]))))
inds[is.infinite(inds)] <- NA
inds
#[1] NA  1 NA  3  2  4  6
```

---

The above method gives a warning, to remove the warning we can perform an additional check of the `length`

```
c(NA, sapply(seq_along(A)[-1], function(x) {
  inds <- which(A[1:(x-1)] == A[x])
 if (length(inds) > 0)
   max(inds)
 else
   NA
}))

#[1] NA  1 NA  3  2  4  6
```

Comment: I like this answer -- but it throws an error upon execution.

Comment: @Nick is that an error or warning? Yes, you might get a warning.

Comment: It's a warning.  Still I'd like to avoid it if possible.  Another problem with this solution is that it's not very fast when you implement it.  I ran this on an array of 13,000 -- took about 5 secs.

Comment: @Nick I have updated the answer which avoids the warning to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` which is more verbose, but easier for me to grok. We start with recording the row_number, make a group for each number we encounter, then record the prior matching row.

```
library(dplyr)
A2 <- A %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(last_match = lag(row)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sapply(seq_along(A)-1, function(x)ifelse(any(a<-A[x+1]==A[sequence(x)]),max(which(a)),NA))
[1] NA  1 NA  3  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I made (based upon Ronak's answer):

```
lastMatch = function(A){
  uniqueItems = unique(A)
  firstInstances = sapply(uniqueItems, function(x){min(which(A == x))}) #for NA
  notFirstInstances = setdiff(seq(A),firstInstances)
  lastMatch_notFirstInstances = sapply(notFirstInstances, function(x) max(which(A[1:(x-1)] == A[x])))
  X = array(0, dim = c(0, length(A)))
  X[firstInstances] = NA
  X[notFirstInstances] = lastMatch_notFirstInstances
  return(X)
}
```